# Vim/Nvim Remote Editing

Tags: linux, ssh, vim, rsync, remote-access

I want to work from my local nvim client on a project on a remote machine. My job requires that I don't store any source code on my local machine and only work on remote (I think writes to /tmp are fine).

There is a lot on the internet about this topic but it constantly evolves, so I need to know if there are new solutions.

What I wanted to do: mount project directory via sshfs and work with nvim normally. However, ssh connection is just too slow and nvim is laggy because of this.

I like the idea of `nvim scp://user@machine/path/to/file` that is offered by netrw, but I need to open and load the entire directory so that my LSP and navigation works well. If netrw provides this some other way, please let me know.

I'm fine with installing software on the remote, like VS Code Remote SSH plugin does. However, I couldn't install distant.nvim on the remote, because it's missing dependencies.

Currently I'm thinking of rsync -> edit -> rsync, but I'm worried that this way I can get caught getting those files locally.

Is there a solution that you regularly use?

Comment: Can't you just SSH into the remote machine and run Vim there? You could even scp your vim-related config files to the remote machine to replicate your presumably customized Vim environment. That way all you're sending across the link is keystrokes, character echoes, and terminal control sequences, which means you're sending a lot less data across the link than if you were using a local tool to edit remote data. If this isn't an option for you for some reason, please edit your Question to make it more clear why you need/want to run Vim locally instead of remotely.

Comment: @Spiff for laggy connections like the OP that would result in stuttering output. VS Code SSH does some buffering or something like that so you can code just like normally

Comment: try [mosh](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh) instead, it claims to use predictive models so it would be `usable on high-latency links, e.g. on a cellular data connection or spotty Wi-Fi.`

Comment: @phuclv We don't know that OP's link itself was laggy. It could be that OP was trying to do things like search for a string across an entire project, which would cause all of the files in the project to have to be read across the sshfs link, which would presumably be slow and be perceived as lag.

Comment: ataha322 - how laggy is laggy? What's the ping time, what the average loss if you check w/ e.g. `mtr`?

Comment: @tink laggy as in laggy network. ping time is 200-300 ms, 0% loss. So just ssh'ing won't work.

Comment: @Spiff I won't edit, I don't think the "why" is important, only the "want". But latency till that machine is 200-300 ms, so the editor has to be local. I also just "want" it to be local for an array of reasons. VS code Remote - SSH achieves this out of the box. I'm also feeling that this is a common problem for remote developers and neovim cultists might have a solution.

Comment: @phuclv thanks for suggestion! I tried but its prediction is good for just using the cli, but not vim, because it cannot predict those motions. Thus, there's no difference in lag. I need something more specific to text editing that will operate on files/directories, it doesn't have to worry about the shell. But thanks, this is indeed useful when I'm using just the shell without text editing.

Comment: @phuclv yes, I'm using it because of this problem, but i would like to use nvim.

Comment: @ataha322 in the mean time you can use the vim extension in VS Code

Comment: @phuclv that's what I'm doing, but I have other nice things in my nvim.